# Covering Radius of linear code

Tags: coding-theory

Covering Radius of a linear code:
 Show that if C is a linear [n, k, d] code over a ﬁnite ﬁeld $F_{q}$, then R ≤ n − k.

Comment: Is this related to sphere packing bound? Well, I guess that somehow we need to show that $M\cdot S_{(R,n)}(\bar{c}) \geq q^{n}$ and since $M = q^{k}$ we can get this. I guess so. Also singleton bound may help if this would be an optimal code since then we can easily prove that $R\leq d-1$. Can someone give some comment on this idea? Sphere with covering radius around a vector $\bar{y}\in \mathbb{F}^{n}$ would include all the possible codewords in it. This gives $q^{k} \leq {n\choose R}(q-1)^{R}$. Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

@Jyrki There you go.....

$G= [I_{k}|X]$ so for every input word $i_{k} \in \mathbb{F}^{k}$ we have a codeword $\bar{c}\in C$: $\bar{c} = [i_{k}|i_{k}\cdot X]$. For every $\bar{y}\in F^{n}$, $\bar{y} = [i_{k}|Y_{n-k}]$ where $Y_{n-k}\in \mathbb{F}^{n-k}$. So it can be easily viewed that for every $\bar{y} \exists \bar{c} : \min d(\bar{y},\bar{c}) \leq n-k$. And taking $\max$ over all gives covering radius.

Answer (score 0):

"Hint":

Without loss of generality we can assume that the code is generated by a systematic generator matrix. This means that to any sequence of $k$ first symbols there exists a codeword beginning with that sequence. Upon reviewing the definition of the covering radius your task is to, given any vector, show that you can turn it into a codeword by changing at most $n-k$ components.